# Lost all my data after putting new block with e2fsck

Tags: mount, disk, fsck

I was trying to fix my corrupted external hard drive (wouldn't mount anymore). I had all the symptoms described in this howto:

https://linuxexpresso.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/repair-a-broken-ext4-superblock-in-ubuntu/

Basically I had a bad superblock (if I understand properly, which might not be the case).

As explained in the link, I ran: `sudo e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sdc` (sdc being my corrupted drive, and 3276 an alternative superblock number).

Output:

```
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
/dev/sdc was not cleanly unmounted, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

/dev/sdc: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/sdc: 11/61046784 files (0.0% non-contiguous), 3849809/244182272 blocks
```

After this, my disk will mount properly, but all my data are gone!!! Am I missing something, or did I do something wrong? Please help!